Running unit tests during pip install when using scikit-build-core with pyproject.toml
Is there a way to automatically test the installation of a python package that is built using scikit-build-core? I already got the C++ unit-tests as part of the C++ build like so, can something like this be done for the python bindings as well?
The test does not necessarily have to be invoked by scikit-build-core, if there is some other mechanism that can be invoked automatically by pip install.
Of course it's not too much effort to run the test manually after install but you also don't want to put the cherry on top of the cake manually after install ;)
While writing this question, I had the idea that this automatic test could also be done by cmake after building the python library, and I actually got it working:
I append this code
# Automatically run the test script after building
add_custom_command(
    TARGET _core
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/${SKBUILD_PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${SKBUILD_PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.py ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_core.*.* ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${SKBUILD_PROJECT_NAME}/
    COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.py
)

to my CMakeLists.txt which basically looks like this.
However, this is somewhat hacky and only tests that the generated lib can be imported to python, not if it's available to the user after installing.
